# Can I combined the trained model between different source but same model structure?

Tags: long-short-term-memory, time-series, models, training-datasets

Here I got two different deep-learning models that were trained by LSTM and time-series data.
The data is the usage percentage of CPU from two different computers.
Each computer job was the same. It was a simple stress test with different stress power and period.
Basically, the target source is the same as CPU. but data is not the same.
Based on two time-series data, I trained the model using LSTM and finally, I got two '*h5' saved models.
As a step of data preprocessing, I applied 'Differencing' which is the removing step in order to erase trends and periodical conditions. And also the scaling by 0 to 1.
Due to the 'Differencing', the model can train the data's potential variation.

And the model will use a future stress test reference and will provide some safety guidelines.

I think the data characteristics are basically the same because it is CPU.
My question is, Can I combine two trained models and believe in the performance?

I didn't validate and test this issue but MY current opinion is,

1. Because of Differencing, Each model might train the CPU's potential variation. So It is already independent of the trend or periodical behavior. Both data can use for the single model.
2. Basically, Each data represented the CPU conditions. Even if one data had a dramatic variation, It can be treated as a special case from long CPU data. big data is always better than small data. so Both data can use for this.

My thought are shown above. I Would like to hear a different or additional opinion from experts.

Thank you for your help!